# SQL Server move Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I shall appreciate some help. I have a table in an SQL Server DB called info_source with the following data:

```
Date        StatCode  Value_1  Value_2  Remarks
----------  --------  -------  -------  -------
2012-11-01  SRC_1     18775     648     Normal
2012-11-01  SRC_2     308218    249     Normal
2012-11-01  SRC_3     0         0       Off
2012-11-02  SRC_4     123181    523     Normal
2012-11-02  SRC_5     189231    247     Normal
```

I will be replacing the `statCode` field with the name of the station using a join. I would like the rows converted to columns to be used in reports something similar to this:

```
Date       StatName   Value_1 Value_2 Remarks StatName   Value_1 Value_2 Remarks
---------- ---------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ------- ------- -------
2012-11-01 (SRC_1)ABC 18775   648     Normal  (SRC_2)DEF 308218  249     Normal
2012-11-02 (SRC_4)JKL 123181  523     Normal  (SRC_5)MNO 189231  247     Normal
```

I was going to create a view but couldn't solve the problem. Than I researched and found some information about pivot tables but I could not get to grips on how to write a query that does what I want.

**EDIT**

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT date AS [date], statCode AS [station], value_1 AS [val1],
 value_2 AS [val2], remarks AS [remks] FROM info_source
) AS query1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Even if what you tried did not work, we appreciate seeing the code.  This proves that you have made an attempt as well as prevents you from getting answers that you have tried already.

Comment: What happened to the SRC_3 row?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I removed that row.

Comment: There's not a way to just say "make the values columns." As you stated, PIVOT will do this, but what it does is make columns from a predefined list and aggregate the values. That's the only way it works and can only do that because 1) it knows the columns ahead of time and 2) it has a way to combine all the values in.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. You didn't bother putting that row in the output you want, but is there a way to determine why *programmatically*? E.g. did you remove that row because the value is 0, or because you only want the first two rows for any date, or because you don't like SRC_3, or ...?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have removed it for the sake of clarity. No there are rows with 0 values in the table and I need to show that data. What I want is grouping the rows by date for a given number of sources (SRC_1, SRC_2, SRC_3 etc)

Comment: @DavidStarkey This is what I have tried so far: select * from 
(
SELECT date as [date], statCode as [station], value_1 as [val1], value_2 as [val2], remarks as [remks] 
From info_source) as query1 but i still have have the data in rows as explained above.

Comment: @johan: When you show your code, please show it in your question. Comments will not allow you to format it well. Besides, in your question it will be more visible.

Comment: @johan Thank you for the information, I have edited your question to include it.

Answer (score 2):

In order you get the result, my suggestion would be to use the `row_number()` windowing function, unpivot your columns `statcode`, `value_1`, `value_2` and `remarks` and finally to apply the PIVOT function.

The first step is to query your data and apply the `row_number()` function.  Since you have multiple rows of data that you want in columns, you need a method to keep the values associated with each other:

```
select date, value_1, value_2, statcode, remarks,
  row_number() over(partition by date
                    order by statcode) seq
from yourtable;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2bf5/3). This will assign a sequential number to each row for each date in your table.  I used the `order by statcode` but if you have another value to keep the items in a specific order, then you will use that column.

Once you have assigned the row number, then you will unpivot the data in the columns `statcode`, `value_1`, `value_2` and `remarks`.  You can use the UNPIVOT function or you can use CROSS APPLY to convert the multiple columns into multiple rows of data.  When you transform the data you will be left with 3 columns, the date, the value of the previous column and then the new column names that will be used in the PIVOT:

```
select date, 
  col = col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10)), 
  value
from
(
  select date, value_1, value_2, statcode, remarks,
    row_number() over(partition by date
                      order by statcode) seq
  from yourtable
) src
cross apply
(
  select 'statcode', statcode union all
  select 'value_1', cast(value_1 as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'value_2', cast(value_2 as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'remarks', remarks
) c (col, value);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2bf5/8). This will give you data in the format:

```
|                            DATE |        COL |  VALUE |
---------------------------------------------------------
| November, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 | statcode_1 |  SRC_1 |
| November, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |  value_1_1 |  18775 |
| November, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |  value_2_1 |    648 |
| November, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |  remarks_1 | Normal |
| November, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 | statcode_2 |  SRC_2 |
| November, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |  value_1_2 | 308218 |
```

Finally you will apply the PIVOT function to the items in the new column I called `col`:

```
select date,
  statcode_1, value_1_1, value_2_1, remarks_1,
  statcode_2, value_1_2, value_2_2, remarks_2,
  statcode_3, value_1_3, value_2_3, remarks_3
from
(
  select date, 
    col = col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10)), 
    value
  from
  (
    select date, value_1, value_2, statcode, remarks,
      row_number() over(partition by date
                        order by statcode) seq
    from yourtable
  ) src
  cross apply
  (
    select 'statcode', statcode union all
    select 'value_1', cast(value_1 as varchar(10)) union all
    select 'value_2', cast(value_2 as varchar(10)) union all
    select 'remarks', remarks
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (statcode_1, value_1_1, value_2_1, remarks_1,
              statcode_2, value_1_2, value_2_2, remarks_2,
              statcode_3, value_1_3, value_2_3, remarks_3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2bf5/9).  Now the above code will work for you is you have a known values, but if you have unknown values, then you will need to use dynamic SQL.  The dynamic SQL code is:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by date
                                                order by statcode) seq
                      from yourtable
                    ) t
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'statcode', 1 union all
                      select 'value_1', 2 union all
                      select 'value_2', 3 union all
                      select 'remarks', 4 
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, seq, so
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT date,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select date, 
                col = col+''_''+cast(seq as varchar(10)), 
                value
              from
              (
                select date, value_1, value_2, statcode, remarks,
                  row_number() over(partition by date
                                    order by statcode) seq
                from yourtable
              ) src
              cross apply
              (
                select ''statcode'', statcode union all
                select ''value_1'', cast(value_1 as varchar(10)) union all
                select ''value_2'', cast(value_2 as varchar(10)) union all
                select ''remarks'', remarks
              ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2bf5/11). Both versions will give a result:

```
|                            DATE | STATCODE_1 | VALUE_1_1 | VALUE_2_1 | REMARKS_1 | STATCODE_2 | VALUE_1_2 | VALUE_2_2 | REMARKS_2 | STATCODE_3 | VALUE_1_3 | VALUE_2_3 | REMARKS_3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| November, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      SRC_1 |     18775 |       648 |    Normal |      SRC_2 |    308218 |       249 |    Normal |      SRC_3 |         0 |         0 |       Off |
| November, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      SRC_4 |    123181 |       523 |    Normal |      SRC_5 |    189231 |       247 |    Normal |     (null) |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |
```